# How to get unique variant option2 values in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a section inside the product page where the user chooses a color of a shirt (as well as the size)

I learned that to get separate values for variant options, I should loop through the variants and get variant.option1 for the first option and variant.option2 for the second option.

However, it's rendering each option multiple times since there's a combination (small + red, large + red, hence renders red twice, for example)

How can I render each color once? uniquely?

Also, if anyone could get me a template I could use that renders multiple variants, I'd really appreciate it. Help online is barely available for Shopify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [uniq](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/uniq/)

```
{% assign options = '' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign options = options | append: ',' | append: variant.option2 %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign options = options | remove_first: ',' | split: ',' | uniq %}

{% for option in options %}
{{ option }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `options` is being turned into `000000ffffff000080`, is there another way I can create a new array and loop through it? Sorry, I'm new to liquid.

Comment: Those looks like concatenated hex values, are they the titles of your variants? You will need to loop through the options to display them one at a time

Comment: I want to use them to render circles that have colors in them, in the products section, I put #000000, #ffffff, #000080 as color options, then I will use these to render circled colors so the user can choose which color he/she wants.

Comment: I'm normally looping over option2, which is the colors, but it's looping multiple times since there's size as well. (small + #ffffff, medium + #ffffff, so it renders #ffffff twice)

Comment: @CedricHadjian I just added some more detail. There should only be unique colours, but you will need to loop over the resulting array to show them how you need them. I added the second loop for you

Comment: I think this won't work. Just realized I also have to pass the id of the variant and I don't know how to do that, and each variant has its own id combined from the size + color... not for each. Will choose your answer as the correct one anyway since you answered what I was initially looking for. Thanks :) I have to research further to find how it works.

Comment: Have a look at the [json](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/additional-filters#json) filter too. You could use it to output all the variant data to a readable format for JS to do the heavy lifting

Comment: I just downloaded a template from elemenets.envato.com so I'm gonna use it to learn and mimic! The best way to learn something is to see it in action haha